# Зачем нужен модификатор члена new?

Tags: c#

На MSDN написано что модификатор new скрывает член базового класса. Но если его не использовать программа отработает также как и с ним, за исключением предупреждения о необходимости его использования.
Зачем он нужен тогда?

Comment: Использование new просто делает это **явно**. Это можно сравнить с использованием модификатора `internal` для класса. Класс по умолчанию объявляется с видимостью `internal`, но можно явно ему прописать `internal class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Он нужен, чтобы дать понять компилятору, что Вы намеренно объявляете член класса-наследника с таким же именем, как имя членa родительского класса.

Comment: Не только это, просто сейчас неудобно дополнить вопрос.

Comment: `Он нужен, чтобы дать понять компилятору, что...` - я бы сказал, что он нужен не компилятору, а тому, кто читает код.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, без него компилятор будет warning писать

Comment: @Grundy, ну так warning тоже для человека, а не для компилятора

Comment: @АндрейNOP, ну так new и говорит компилятору - не писать warning

Comment: @Grundy, так компилятор собирает прекрасно и без new, new ему не нужен

Comment: @АндрейNOP но при этом пишет warning :-)

Comment: Мне кажется, или здесь произошла рекурсия? :)

Comment: @Grundy тут две стороны по-своему правы. Да, компилятору нужно ключевое слово new, чтобы сгенерировать warning для юзера. Но если бы не было цели показать warning пользователю, то компилятору этот warning не нужен. По сути warning - это встроенные в компилятор правила подсказок, как можно улучшить код. Поэтому две стороны правы.